# How to make Windows Media Player 12 read the refreshed tags from mp3 files?

Tags: windows-7, mp3, windows-media-player, tags

I am running Windows Media Player on Windows 7. I altered the tag information on my `mp3` files, and the WMP does not update them in the library. Is there a way to force it to refresh the tags, short of deleting the library and building it anew?

Thank you.

Comment: WMP should update its library automatically on external tag changes. This not happening could point to a corrupted library, which can only be fixed by deleting the library database files and letting it rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one workaround. Right-clicking on any file in the changed album and selecting `Edit` and then pressing `Esc` to cancel the changes forced the refresh of the labels.